# meaning of "status" and "condiciones"

Tags: vocabulary, medieval-latin, latin-to-english-translation

I'm reading Olaus Magnus's 1550 *Historia de gentibus septentrionalibus, earumque diversis statibus, condicionibus, moribus, ritibus, superstitionibus, disciplinis, exercitiis, regimine, victu, bellis, structuris, instrumentis, ac mineris metallicis, et rebus mirabilibus, necnon universis paene animalibus in Septentrione degentibus, eorumque natura*. It's a fascinating book, but I can't figure out what *status* and *condiciones* are intended to refer to in the title. I mean, obviously "states" and "conditions," but those are words so broad as to be all but meaningless in this context, and I feel like Magnus actually means something very specific by each one.

Any thoughts on what those somethings very specific might be?